# How to force NFS to keep files on client side?

Tags: linux, fedora, nfs

I have an NFS server in a headless Fedora Server 35 VM configured as follow:

```
File: /etc/exports
/development 10.211.55.0/24(rw,all_squash,async,no_subtree_check,anonuid=0,anongid=0)
```

Then in my Mac Book Pro (MBP), I run the following command to mount the shared folder:

```
sudo mount -o resvport,rw -t nfs fedora-server-development:/development ~/development
```

Everything works fine till the minute I restart the MBP or umount the folder by running:

```
sudo diskutil unmount force ~/development
```

What is not working? The content disappears from the client and I want to keep it on the MBP side as well. The reason is simple: if by any chance the VM gets corrupted I will lose all my work.

Is there a way to force NFS to keep the files/folders on the client-side when the VM is shut down or the MBP gets restarted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cant keep files on your client by using NFS  - NFS (As Network File Server implies) stores the files on the server and allows them to be accessed/modified by client.

NFS is an ancient technology which is much simpler then systems that syndicate files.  You might want to investigate alternative technologies like rsync and Nextcloud, but if this is development work as in coding, GIT is the go-to solution.